# How can i connect Microsoft AX client to an AOS instance installed on a server hosted in Azure cloud?

Tags: azure, cloud, ax

I have Microsoft AX client installed on my pc and i have to reach and connect to an AOS (Ax Object Server) which is hosted in the MS Azure cloud, within a network.

The problem is the client seems that cant reach the server. I opened all the ports needed on the server through Azure but the client still give error...

I really need help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your client firewall? If you've opened the endpoints in azure portal then you should be able to connect to the vm on those ports.